# Regex: exclude all even/odd matches

Tags: php, regex

The question itself is pretty self explanatory. But I want to clear up something: I'm not asking for a regex which does not match if the number of matches is odd/even. I'm asking for a regex that excludes all odd/even matches.

Also, here's my regex which should work in the solution : `(?<=\*)[^*]*(?=\*)`

The final goal is to replace the leading and trailing asterisks without modifying or losing the strings between the asterisks.

Comment: So there's no special argument which the regex excludes even/odd matches and once can only have to find their own way to do that?

Comment: Regex is a pattern string, some text. It is used by some programming language to find pieces of text. You just need to write the regex correctly and use it with the right regex function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because the asterisks on both ends of the matches need to be consumed, else, the trailing asterisk will become the next match start position.

You need to *consume* these strings while *capturing* the data between the two asterisks, then obtain the Group 1 values:

```php
if (preg_match_all('~\*([^*]*)\*~', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/sCjdO).

To replace the asterisks only, without touching the content in between, you can use

```php
$text = 'Abc *def* ghi *jkl*';
echo preg_replace('~\*([^*]*)\*~', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
// => Abc <b>def</b> ghi <b>jkl</b>
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/B3VfL).